# Usecallback fail to memorization

Tags: javascript, reactjs, usecallback

I have the following code where changes on the parent component cause child element re - render. Basically the Menu component should be appear by right click on top of the placeholder tag but when it appears the whole parent component flickers. I used Usecallback with no luck. I tried useMemo but it doesn't accept any arguments. Since my callback functions are firing as a result of events, passing target of the event is important. Therefore I should pass the argument. I appreciate any suggestion.

```
const [menu, setMenu] = useState({isActive: false, position: undefined});

    <div className='placeholder'
        onClick={clickHandler}
        onContextMenu={rightClickHandler}>
        {menu.isActive && <Menu menu={menu} />}
        {[props.entity].map(plc => {
            let Content = place[props.entity];
            if(Content) {
                return <Content key={Math.random()} />
            }
        })}
    </div>

    const rightClickHandler = useCallback((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const parentPosition = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const position = {
            left: e.clientX - parentPosition.left,
            top: e.clientY - parentPosition.top
        };
        setMenu(
            {
                isActive: (menu.isActive ? menu.isActive: !menu.isActive),
                position: {
                    left: position.left,
                    top: position.top
                }
            }
        );
    }, []);

    const clickHandler = useCallback((e) => {
        setMenu({isActive: false, module: '', position: undefined});
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `Math.random()` It will reinforce the component to re render

```
const [menu, setMenu] = useState({isActive: false, position: undefined});

    <div className='placeholder'
        onClick={clickHandler}
        onContextMenu={rightClickHandler}>
        {menu.isActive && <Menu menu={menu} />}
        {[props.entity].map((plc, i) => {
            let Content = place[props.entity];
            if(Content) {
                return <Content key={'somethingElse' + i} />
            }
        })}
    </div>

    const rightClickHandler = useCallback((e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const parentPosition = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        const position = {
            left: e.clientX - parentPosition.left,
            top: e.clientY - parentPosition.top
        };
        setMenu(
            {
                isActive: (menu.isActive ? menu.isActive: !menu.isActive),
                position: {
                    left: position.left,
                    top: position.top
                }
            }
        );
    }, []);



 const clickHandler = useCallback((e) => {
            setMenu

({isActive: false, module: '', position: undefined});
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need useCallback for this if you use this way. I hope this solves it.

```
const rightClickHandler = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  const parentPosition = e.target.getBoundingClientRect()
  const position = {
    left: e.clientX - parentPosition.left,
    top: e.clientY - parentPosition.top,
  }
  setMenu((menu) => {
    return {
      isActive: menu.isActive ? menu.isActive : !menu.isActive,
      position,
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: No, still the same